# Google Tag Manager API stopped working. gapi.client.load not loading tag manager api v2

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-apis-explorer

I am working on a tool that uses google tag manager API. gapi.client.load is unable to load tag manager api and throwing "Invalid Argument" Error.

I tried to search this problem but wasn't able to find a solution for it. Seems like this issue has been raised on google-api-javascript-client https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/539.

This is the error i am getting. [Error message](https://ibb.co/cC5V5nf)